# Run function on enter press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery button function that works properly and executes the code inside, what I want is when I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the search box, it will execute the same function inside the onclick one. I don't want to copy paste the entire code of my function to the on <kbd>Enter</kbd> press event because that will be the wrong way to do it. This is the click event:

```
$("#checkScout").click(function(e){
 ...
}
```

And this is the one I tried with the on enter press

```
var enterKey = document.getElementById("addChannelsToScout");
enterKey.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $("#checkScout").click(function (e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you notice that your code contains syntax errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be just

```
$("#checkScout").click();
```

so

```
$('#addChannelsToScout').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#checkScout").click();
        //$("#checkScout").trigger('click');
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gVjmv/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#checkScout").trigger('click');
```

**[Trigger Performance](http://jsperf.com/trigger-vs-not-trigger)**

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 $("#checkScout").click(function(e);
```

To:

```
  $("#checkScout").click();
```

Your code:

```
var enterKey = document.getElementById("addChannelsToScout");
    enterKey.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) 
        {  
          $("#checkScout").click();//modified here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just this will work `$("#checkScout").click();`

```
var enterKey = document.getElementById("addChannelsToScout");
    enterKey.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) 
        {  
          $("#checkScout").click();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you need to trigger the event. since it is already been handled it will perform the task that you have written in the event

Check Triggers here http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$("#checkScout").trigger("click");
```